# Is there a fixed point operator in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, fixed-point-iteration

I recently noticed that I quite often write functions which just iterates another function `f` until it reaches a fixed point (such that `f x == x`)

I thought this is a pretty general concept, so I think there might be a built in.

So I was wondering whether there is a built in for this, or something more general?

So I'm basically looking for this:

```
fixedpoint f x= head . dropWhile(\y->y /= f y) $ iterate f x
```

I just had trouble googling this, because I only found references to the `fix` function whenever my search term contained `fixed point` or something similar.

Comment: `ghci` says that the type of that function is `Eq a => (a -> a) -> a -> a`. Hoogle doesn't seem to return useful results for that signature.

Comment: The closest thing is `until :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a` `until p f yields the result of applying f until p holds.` - it seems like you could write your function using it but you still need the `Eq` constraint

Comment: @Daenyth Thanks, I didn't know you could use hoogle that way=) If you add it as an answer I'd accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function has the signature `Eq a => (a -> a) -> a -> a`.

[Using hoogle to search for that](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Eq+a+%3D%3E+%28a+-%3E+a%29+-%3E+a+-%3E+a), I don't see any exact matches. The closest match is `until`

> `until :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a`
>
> base Prelude
>
> `until p f` yields the result of applying `f` until `p` holds.

You could likely use that to write your function but because you need `/=` you need the `Eq` constraint.

Comment: You could use `until` with pairs, but I think it's simpler to just do the whole thing by hand.

Comment: or `last . takeWhileDifferent . iterate f`, or similar write own `last . takeWhileDifferent` variant... takeWhileDifferent = https://github.com/ekmett/ad/blob/ac5e0c7091430d0c569ba893f78385ead70b918e/src/Numeric/AD/Internal/Combinators.hs#L51

Answer (score 5):

Just write it yourself. A direct version will be faster than one using `dropWhile`.

```
hammer :: Eq a => (a -> a) -> a -> a
hammer f x
  | x' == x = x'
  | otherwise = hammer f x'
  where x' = f x
```

Comment: I know there are many ways to do it, but I'm explicitly looking for a built in, as I'm assuming it is a quite commonly funciton.

Comment: @flawr, I don't think it's particularly common, actually. `until` seems closest, but actually using it for this purpose is more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are looking for a build-in because you want a short expression  without any auxiliary functions, I can recommend

```hs
until=<<((==)=<<) :: Eq a => (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

Arguably this looks a bit strange, but in fact it is just the point-free equivalent to `until (\x -> f x == x) f`, using the fact that `f (g x) x` can be expressed by `(f=<<g) x` twice.